# Having issue with sns.scatterplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like your help in explaining and fixing this issue.

I runner the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([[0, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [0, 2], [2, 2], [5, 1], [5, 2], [2, 4], [4, 4], [5, 5]])
y_1 = np.array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1])
y_2 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1])

sns.scatterplot(x[:,1],x[:,0], hue=y_1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

And got the following output :

[image]

If you noticed the only difference between y_1 and y_2 is just the change of the number -1 by 0

And after running the same code :

```
sns.scatterplot(x[:,1],x[:,0], hue=y_2)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have no idea why there is an extra-label `0` in the first plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's indeed a [known issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1653) in seaborn.

A workaround ([credit](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1653#issuecomment-536680369)) is to modify `y_1` before passing it as `hue`. Try:

```
sns.scatterplot(x[:,1],x[:,0], hue=["$%s$" % x for x in y_1])
```

Output:

[image]